# How to select a column only if it exists?

Tags: sql, select, conditional-statements

I need to write a sql-query, which selects a column, only if it exists.
Since I'm selecting from a table, which has a slightly different appearance at every costumer.

```
SELECT dbo.Table1.Column0, dbo.Table1.Column1, dbo.Table1.Column2

   AND (IF dbo.Table1.EXISTS(Column3)
   (dbo.Table1.Column3))

FROM dbo.Table1 

WHERE (Column0 = @C1 and Column2 = @C2)
```

Comment: If the tables in the query are static, surely you at the time of writing the query whether the column exists or not?

Comment: Do you want to replace `Column0` with another name when you run this? Not sure that I understand the question correctly.

Comment: my example might have been to complicated, i made it more simple, what is neccesary to me is select column3 only if it exists

Comment: Please post the type of database you are querying against

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `SELECT * FROM FROM dbo.Table1` and ignoring `Column3` on the other end if it is not being used?